# What is the correct way to use lambda expression in .stream() and in Collectors?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
   Map<String, EmailAddress> mapAliasAddress;
        mapAliasAddress = Files.lines(Paths.get("emails.csv"))
                .map(s->s.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.groupBy(s->s[1], new EmailAddress(s->s[1],s->[0])));// first is the alias, second is the email address
```

This is EmailAddress an object class which take in two parameters(alias and email_address)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: Do not post images. And what is `Collectors.group`?

Comment: The syntax is wrong have the compliation error

Comment: You did it right for the first parameter of the collector.

Comment: This expression `new EmailAddress(s->s[1],s->[0])` should be this: `s -> new EmailAddress(s[1],s[0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
Map<String, EmailAddress> mapAliasAddress;
mapAliasAddress = Files.lines(Paths.get("emails.csv"))
            .map(s->s.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[1], s -> new EmailAddress(s[1], s[0]);
```

Comment: Collecting into a list and storing it as a `Map<String, EmailAddress>` can't work.

Comment: not correct see that the targeted output is a Map but your collect() will return a List

Comment: Works :) @DanilGaponov